# Torsion-free group with a subgroup of finite index

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Torsion-free virtually-Z is Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70497/torsion-free-virtually-z-is-z)

Let $G$ be a torsion-free group with a subgroup $H$ of finite index isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Is $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If this is a homework question, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: It is not a homework. I just met torsion-free groups and I tried to find some basic properties of it. I was unable to solve this question.

Comment: The question has been asked there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70497/torsion-free-virtually-z-is-z

Comment: Okay. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we say $G$ is "virtually $\mathcal{P}$" if it has a subgroup $H$ that has property $\mathcal{P}$ and is of finite index in $G$. When the property $\mathcal{P}$ is inherited to subgroups (if $H$ has property $\mathcal{P}$, and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $K$ has property $\mathcal{P}$), then in fact $G$ is virtually $\mathcal{P}$ if and only if it has a *normal* subgroup with property $\mathcal{P}$ that is of finite index (since every subgroup of $G$ of finite index contains a normal subgroup of $G$ of finite index).

So your question is whether a torsion-free virtually cyclic group must be cyclic.

The answer is "yes": in fact, a virtually cyclic group must be either finite (every finite group is virtually cyclic), finite by infinite cyclic, or finite by infinite-dihedral. For a proof of the case you are interested in, see [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70497/torsion-free-virtually-z-is-z).