# A finite union of infinite cyclic subgroups of a group $G$ is never a group.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

$\mathbf{Question}$: Consider an infinite group $G$. Let $\langle a_1\rangle , \langle a_2\rangle, \ldots, \langle a_m\rangle $ ($\langle a_i\rangle =C_i$) be a finite collection of infinite cyclic subgroups of $G$ such that $C_i \not\subset C_j$ for $i \neq j$. Then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^mC_i$ is never a subgroup of $G$. ($m>1$)

$\mathbf{A \ restricted \ version:}$ Consider an infinite commutative group $G$. Let $<a_1>, <a_2>, ..., <a_m>$ ($<a_i>=C_i$) be a finite collection of infinite cyclic subgroups of $G$ such that $C_j \not\subset \displaystyle\bigcup_{I \setminus \{j\}}C_i$ , $I=\{1,2,3,...,m\}$. Then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^mC_i$ is never a subgroup of $G$. ($m>1$)

I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The statement is certainly wrong as stated. I mean, what happens if $m=1$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $m>1$. It is certainly not of much interest when $m=1$.  But yes, it must be mentioned that $m>1$

Comment: Then **fix it**! We aren’t responsible for reading your mind of figuring out what conditions you *should* have put into your query. If you don’t put them, then they aren’t there. So right now, **you’re wrong.** If you don’t want to be wrong, then fix it in the body of the problem, not flippantly in the comments.

Comment: Ok. So is there a thing like $\cup_{i=1}^1$? The reason I did not mention it, because I have never seen the consideration anywhere.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I will try to keep this in mind

Comment: I do not see on what grounds you claim to be able to omit $C_1$ from the union.

Comment: The proposed proof does not explicitly use the assumption that each $a_i$ has infinite order, which is necessary given the example involving $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @GabeConant Would the fact "every infinite cyclic group has only two generators" be of any help?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a full proof, but it excludes large classes of groups and is way too long to fit into a comment.

I'm going to prove that no nontrivial group $G$ is the union of finitely many infinite cyclic subgroups, unless $G=\Bbb Z$ or $G$ is a noncommutative group with one end.

Suppose that $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \langle c_i\rangle$ where $n>1$ and $\langle c_i\rangle\simeq \Bbb Z$ for every $i$, in particular every element in $G$ has infinite order and $G$ is finitely generated. By a famous result of Freudenthal and Hopf $G$ has either $1,2$ or infinitely many ends, we look at this cases separately.

If $G$ has a single end and $G$ is abelian then $G\simeq\Bbb Z^m$, for $m>1$, by the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, and it's easy to show that $\Bbb Z^m$ is not the union of finitely many cyclic subgroups, by explicitely constructing an element not contained in such an union.

If $G$ has a single end and $G$ isn't abelian I can't conclude the proof, and it's the only missing case.

If $G$ has two ends then another result of Freudenthal and Hopf shows that $G$ must be virtually $\Bbb Z$ and it's known that a torsion free virtually $\Bbb Z$ group is either trivial or $\Bbb Z$ (see for example [here](https://planetmath.org/VirtuallyCyclicGroup) for a reference), which concludes the proof in this case (since it's easy to show that $\Bbb Z$ isn't the union of more than one infinite cyclic subgroup).

If $G$ has more than two ends then it must have infinitely many. Pick a ball in the Cayley graph whose complement has infinitely many connected components. The subspace $\langle c_i\rangle$ of the Cayley graph (meaning the vertices $c_i^n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ and the edges joining $c_i^n$ to $c_i^{n+1}$) is connected for every $i$, so it is clear that finitely many such subspaces can't cover the complement of the chosen ball, hence they can't cover the vertices of the Cayley graph either and thus $G$ is not the union of the $\langle c_i\rangle$, a contradiction.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on your infinite ends case, though. By "ball", do you mean a (word)-metric ball of finite radius? Because those don't ever have to have infinitely many connected complements, just arbitrarily many. Consider a free group. Even then, you're also disconnecting the cyclic groups, so it's not clear why the number of connected components of each cyclic group can't also grow without bound.

Comment: Ah right, I agree that this doesn't work as written, what I want to say is that I'm looking at the Cayley graph wrt the generating set $\{c_i\}$, so that every $\langle c_i\rangle$ is a connected subspace of the Cayley graph and it can cover at most two ends. To see that pick a ball $B_n$ and fix $i$. There is a minimum $z\in \Bbb Z$ with $c_i^z\in B_n$ (since $B_n$ is finite). Since $\langle c_i\rangle$ is connected the subgraph induced by $\{c_i^k\mid k<z\}$ covers at most one end. There is also a biggest $l$ such that $c_i^k\not\in B_n$ for $k>l$. The subgraph induced by

Comment: $\{c_i^k\mid k>l\}$ covers at most one end, again by the connectedness of $\langle c_i\rangle$. $\langle c_i\rangle\setminus B_n$ could have more connected components, but they are all finite except those two, so they can't cover any end. (hopefully it works now)

Comment: When I say "by connectedness of $\langle c_i\rangle$ I really mean "because taking the complement of a ball always splits it into two infinite connected components and a bunch we don't care about". The point is that $\langle c_i\rangle$ can't jump between two connected components of the complement of a ball in the Cayley graph without going through that ball again. This is getting messy to write, it might be easier to argue that $\langle c_i\rangle$ is not ramifying...

Comment: Here's how I would phrase it: since there are infinitely many ends, consider 2n+1 of them. Each end is a distinct sequence of nested, unbounded, connected components of the complements of $B(e,k)$, so there must be a finite r such that each of these ends is a different unbounded component of $X = \Gamma \setminus B(e,r)$. But as argued, each $X \cap \langle c_i \rangle$ can have only 2 unbounded components, so there can be at most 2n unbounded components of X, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $G$ is a group and $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^m C_i$ where each $C_i$ is an infinite cyclic subgroup. Note that $G$ must be torsion-free. By [B. H. Neumann’s Lemma](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/B._H._Neumann%27s_lemma), some $C_i$ has finite index. So $G$ is torsion-free and *virtually cyclic* (i.e., has a cyclic subgroup of finite index). It follows that $G$ is cyclic (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70497/torsion-free-virtually-z-is-z)).

Now it’s easy to show that that we can’t have $C_i$ and $C_j$ mutually incomparable when $i\neq j$ (unless $m=1$).